# Android: how to use XML for custom view layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm coming from the world of GWT and UIBinder, where I'm used to defining custom components by extending Composite, and then putting all the UI layout code in a MyComponent.ui.xml file. This is a very nice way to build up components from smaller pieces.

I'm trying to achieve the same effect on Android with custom Views. I've been able to programmatically extend `View`, and then add objects by calling `addView(textView)`. I'd like to be able to do that in XML, but I don't see how to associate an xml layout file with the view (apart the primary `res/layout/main.xml` file, which provides the primary layout for the app.

How can I layout my custom views in XML?

**Edit:** My question was unclear. What I'm looking to do is associate a `my_widget.xml` file with my customized view. Then in my_widget.xml I'd like to define various TextViews, etc, and plug them into my View class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To construct Views from XML, use [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Answer (score 13):

Use the fully qualified name of your custom view class in place of one of the built-in views. Here's a layout, for instance, that fills the window with your class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my.package.MyCustomView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findViewById (int id)` with an id defined in XML. See the example in the android doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (scroll down to **IDs**).